# How to move window when dragging frame pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

i want dragging window using QFrame in pyqt5.
try for function mouseMoveEvent but i get error about move()
add mouseMoveEvent function for moving but don't work and back error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 47, in
> mouseMoveEvent
> self.move(self.pos() + event.globalPos() - self.dragPos) AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'move'

this is my sample code create from ui file to py using pyuic5

**main.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import t

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        
        # Remove title bar
        MainWindow.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) 
        MainWindow.resize(800, 450)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 450))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 450))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow {background: transparent; }\n"
"QToolTip {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgba(27, 29, 35, 160);\n"
"    border: 1px solid rgb(40, 40, 40);\n"
"    border-radius: 2px;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 450))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame {\n"
"background-image: url(:/1/welcome.jpg);\n"
"}")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        # Connect frame to mouseMoveEvent
        self.frame.mouseMoveEvent = self.mouseMoveEvent
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(self.pos() + event.globalPos() - self.dragPos)
            self.dragPos = event.globalPos()
            event.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not modify the code generated by Qt Designer but create another class that inherits
from the appropriate widget and use the initial class to fill it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#import t

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        
        # Remove title bar
        MainWindow.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) 
        MainWindow.resize(512, 450)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(512, 450))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(512, 450))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow {background: transparent; }\n"
"QToolTip {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgba(227, 29, 35, 160);\n"
"    border: 1px solid rgb(40, 40, 40);\n"
"    border-radius: 2px;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 512, 512))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame {\n"
"background-image: url(lena.jpg);\n"
"}")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        # Connect frame to mouseMoveEvent
        self.frame.mouseMoveEvent = self.mouseMoveEvent
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    

#    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
#        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
#            self.move(self.pos() + event.globalPos() - self.dragPos)
#            self.dragPos = event.globalPos()
#            event.accept()


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.dragPos = QtCore.QPoint()
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):                                 # +
        self.dragPos = event.globalPos()
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):                                  # !!!
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(self.pos() + event.globalPos() - self.dragPos)
            self.dragPos = event.globalPos()
            event.accept()        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: can i remove black background window?? are you have idea for this?

Comment: i found it : `MainWindow.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)`